# Why doesn't Rails parameter wrapping include things globbed from the URI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

The [docs on parameter wrapping](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) state:

> Wraps the parameters hash into a nested hash. This will allow clients to submit POST requests without having to specify any root elements.

It helpfully elides *which* parameters hash is being wrapped. The [Action Controller overview guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#path_parameters-query_parameters-and-request_parameters) gives this run-down:

> Rails collects all of the parameters sent along with the request in the `params` hash, whether they are sent as part of the query string or the post body. […] The `query_parameters` hash contains parameters that were sent as part of the query string while the `request_parameters` hash contains parameters sent as part of the post body. The `path_parameters` hash contains parameters that were recognized by the routing as being part of the path leading to this particular controller and action.

The fun happens when you use RESTful resources and routes. Say you have a model A which has_many Bs; B thus has a foreign key `a_id`.

You `POST /as/1/bs` with an empty payload (because B has no other fields). Assuming `a_id` is `attr_accessible`, one might assume that `a_id` would be wrapped in a `b` object. Instead you'll see:

```
Processing by BsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"b"=>{}, "a_id" => "1"}
```

No such luck. It turns out that [`ParamsWrapper` uses `request_parameters`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5e1b92044c8f2afa9e0b80095a9c9defbeaaf2e2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb#L194) and not `params`, so not including `a_id` in the POST payload means it doesn't get wrapped. This is pretty confusing, because you still see it included in `params`, due to URI globbing, and wonder why it got excluded of all things.

Is there any good reason to use `request_parameters` and not `params` here?

I can understand that, from a "REST philosophy" point of view, it's more pure if we assume that the payload contains the entire object, but that essentially means that the `a_id` in the URI is completely ignored, which seems a pity.

**tl;dr:** `ParamsWrapper` uses `request_parameters` as the parameter source, so URI-globbed variables are skipped. Is this a Rails bug? Pure REST advocates may say no, but pragmatism suggests yes.

Comment: Hello! Have you figured out how to get around this issue?

Comment: @dan: unfortunately I haven't worked with Rails since a few months after I posted this question, so I have nothing!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the reason a_id is not included in the hash for 'b' is we need that id value to first check if the record exists in our database. This way, we can simply reject other params in the request. As per the reason for not including it in 'b' hash: It can prevent accidents. Take this scenario: Suppose someone is updating a form and passes complete 'b' hash as an argument to a model object. Now when we call model_object.save, it may save the record in our database instead of updating older record which will be a security threat (Can happen if the object has been initialized earlier). Not a full proof scenario, but accidents do happen while coding and it can help us prevent such accidents.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your specific use case, but if you're using strong params in your controller, you can do either

```
params[:b][:a_id] = params[:a_id]
params.require(:b).permit(:a_id)
```

or just skip the "require" method entirely:

```
params.permit(:a_id)
```